# How to make the 1x/2x icon appear on an iPad for a PhoneGap project

Tags: ios, ipad, cordova

I have a PhoneGap project that is basically an HTML page with some AJAX thrown in. When using/testing other iOS apps, I've seen that in my iPad there is a 1x or 2x button in the lower right hand corner to switch the size of the viewing area. (1x is small like an iPhone, 2x is pretty much fully screen iPad). Thanks !